# CSS: Scrollable menu bar with hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to create a menu with a CSS hover dropdown, basically following this example https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp.

However, my menu is very wide and should be scrollable. It works in principle but after scrolling the dropdown appears at the original position rather at the scrolled position. How can I fix this?

[image: The dropdown appears at the wrong place]

I understand that I should give `.scrollmenu` the attribute `position: relative`  for it to respect the scroll position. But then the dropdown stops working.

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#support">Support</a>
  <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
  <a href="#tools">Tools</a>  
  <a href="#base">Base</a>
  <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
  <a href="#more">More</a>
  <a href="#logo">Logo</a>
  <a href="#friends">Friends</a>
  <a href="#partners">Partners</a>
  <a href="#people">People</a>
  <a href="#work">Work</a>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to implement a solution like shown here, https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/